# Image Can't upload in folder

Tags: php, html

When i am trying to store the image in folder.I can't able to store the image.it shows upload failed error message.
Here i am using this code to store the image:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']); 
echo "<p>";
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);` before `if`...check path is correct or not

Comment: yes i was create one folder name like uploads and save with in the www folder.

Comment: The output is like:   Upload failed

Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => ja-proin.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpUpoHjx
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 7381
        )

)

Answer (score 1):

This could have many causes. Have you checked the upload file size limit in your php.ini? Both  `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size` come to mind.

Also check the permissions on the directory you're moving them to.

Comment: Thank you brother.now image is upload into the folder.now i am trying to retrieving image from the folder and display into the page.But the image was not displaying,it shows like broken image.why?

Comment: You're using `basename` as destination path, but that doesn't include the filetype. I suggest using `pathinfo` to help with that: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)